# Running Visual c# windows application over LAN

Tags: c#, deployment, network-share

This is my first windows application. I have published my project and here are few questions.

1. Now I have two files - a Setup.exe file and a ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest file. However both install my application in the machine. What is the right file I should be relying on while installing at the client's place? What is the difference between these two?
2. Should my application be installed at each client machine? Or would it work if I install my application in the server and try to access the shortcut from a client machine (through LAN)? Would it work? If it is running over LAN, should the client machine have .NET framework installed?

Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what your program does? It would probably affect the answers you get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your question contains some answers.

Ans 1. Setup.exe and ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest file both will install your application but when u run setup.exe it will install all requirements that your app require.

Lets say your app uses .Net Framework 4.0 and Crystal Reports. Then in the setup project(i hope u r using Setup and deployment project of Visual Studio) rightclick on project and click on properties
[image]

Then click on prerequisites... It will show u list of prerequisites available. Check on .Net Framework 4.0 and Crystal Reports and compile your project.

Now when u run setup.exe it will first search for .Net 4.0 Framework and crystal report. If not found it will install them and then proceed for your software installation

OR

if already installed then will directly jump for your software installation.

This will not happen if you directly install your software from ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest file.

Ans 2. U have to install your software on each client for if there is not framework. it will not run your app.

Comment: Ans 1 is clear. Thanks, Now I get what is the difference between those files. Coming again to Qn2. Just in case if .net Framework is already installed in the client machine, would it be possible to access and run the application from the Server thro LAN without the need to install my application in each client machine?

Comment: Yes. It's possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying using ClickOnce you will be installing it on each client machine (this is fine) and the relevant .NET framework(s) installed on each client - these can be installed as a pre-requisite of the application install by configuring the ClickOnce settings.

For ClickOnce the main setup file is setup.exe but it relies on the other files in the deploy package, so asking which specific file is most important isn't really relevant.

If there is a reason you don't want to install the application on each client then you may want to look into developing an IIS (web) application or using a product like Citrix to enable access to the application from the server.

Answer (score -1):

i have a same type of windows application.
currently this application is in use.
if you don't want to install with client PC now you do not have to create the windows application you have to create web application because in windows application you have to install your setup.exe in each client PC.You can not access windows application without install in client PC.